# AlertDialog and image for SetPositiveButton

Tags: android, xamarin, android-alertdialog

We have this:

```
alertadd.SetPositiveButton("To Close", (senderAlert, args) =>
{
Toast.MakeText(this, "Closed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
});
```

Can we have an image for SetPositiveButton? We have "To Close" for SetPositiveButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach your own view to dialog and style your buttons whatever you want. For example:

```
var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_layout, null);
var buttonYes = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.yesButton);
var buttonNo = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.noButton);
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialogBuilder.SetView(view);
            var ad = dialogBuilder.Create();
            ad.Show();
```